# Java 17 access jdk.internal.access

Tags: java, jvm

I recently tried to access `jdk.internal.access` on java 17 to use `SharedSecrets.getJavaLangAccess().addEnableNativeAccess(...)` because `CLinker.getInstance()` ensures if the caller has native access, but it didn't work. Also Java has removed the VM argument `--illegal-access=permit` for Java 17.

Exception:
`java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class <class> (in module <module>) cannot access class jdk.internal.access.SharedSecrets (in module java.base) because module java.base does not export jdk.internal.access to module <module>`

Comment: CLinker is part of an incubating API and is subject to major changes anyhow, so why are you bothering to use with JDK 17? In JDK 19 (to be released in a couple of weeks) the foreign memory features have changed considerably. It's still only a preview feature and so it can change again.

Comment: Why do you think, specifying `-illegal-access=permit` (if it still was supported) is better than specifying `--enable-native-access` in the first place?